# my MKAnnotationVIew is not showing the title

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am new to iPhone programming and I can't understand why the MKAnnotationView is not showing the title's of my annotation's. Below is the code that is used to display it on the map.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
NSLog(@"Entered didAddAnnotationViews");

MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 250, 250);
[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Here is where I am defining my annotations:

```
MapPoint *mp = [[MapPoint alloc]
                    initWithCoordinate:[newLocation coordinate]
                                 title:[locationTitleField text]];

[mapView addAnnotation:mp];
[mp release];
```

mp is a class I have created to keep track of all the map points:

```
#import "MapPoint.h"

@implementation MapPoint
@synthesize coordinate, title;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t
{
[super init];
coordinate = c;
[self setTitle:t];
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[title release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I am beginner so go easy, and all help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
did you look at apple "MapCallouts" example?
you can find it here -

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html

look at it and i would love to help if you have more questions.

shani